# How to return Right class from Either?

Tags: scala

If I have a method that returns `Either` like this

```
def myMethod(s: String): Either[List[SomethingElse], Color] = {
 ....
}
```

And I have a case class like this:

```
case class ColorShade (color: Color, shade: Shade = Shade())
```

How can I return `Color` from `myMethod` and assign to `color` in `ColorShade`. The below doesn't work:

```
Color(Right(myMethod(someString)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Either` is right biased, you can do this.

```
myMethod("string").map(ColorShade(_, shadeValue))
```

The result is `Either[List[SomethingElse],ColorShade]`.

It might be more idiomatic to use a `fold` where you can specify what happens when `myMethod()` returns a `Left`.

```
myMethod("string").fold(se => /*do something with the SomethingElse list*/
                       , ColorShade(_, shadeValue))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about anything else and are happy with the risk of throwing an exception, you can do:

```
ColorShade(myMethod("someString").toOption.get)
```

However, that is not the idiomatic, nor recommended way of doing this.

If you can think of a reasonable default, you could do this:

```
val defaultColor : Color = ???
ColorShade(myMethod("someString").getOrElse(defaultColor))
```

The most idiomatic way would probably be to change whatever is using the `ColorShade` to accept an `Either[List[SomethingElse], ColorShade]`. The advantage is that you will keep the information in the case of `Left` (maybe for error logging purposes). To do that you can do:

```
myMethod("someString").map(color => ColorShade(color))
```

This would be of type `Either[List[SomethingElse], ColorShade]`. Also, should you not need the `Left` information, you might still want to do `toOption` to transform it into an `Option[ColorShade]`.

Answer (score 0):

The usual thing to do would be to map over it so that the final result is also an Either:

```
myMethod(someString).right.map(c => ColorShade(c, someShade))
```

This returns `Either[List[SomethingElse], ColorShade]`.

Note: as of Scala 2.12, you can drop the `.right` part, as Either is now right-biased.